# undefined function or variable in class

Tags: arrays, matlab, class, oop, matlab-class

How to output class property so that it can be accessed in MATLAB's terminal? In my case, `ClassA` stores `p` array and shows output like:

```
 ClassA with properties:

    p: [3x3 double]
```

But when I want to access the array, its always says undefined function or variable. Although its `public`.

My Code:

```
classdef Input
    properties
        p
    end
    methods
        function obj = Input()
            [obj.p] = input('Enter array like [a b c; d e f;]');
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please use proper Indented code (Press ctrl+I in your matlab editor), it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to clear all instances of `Input` classes and `rehash` your path to update the definition of the class.

I get:

```
>> myIn = Input;
Enter array like [a b c; d e f;][1 2 3; 4 5 6]
>> myIn
myIn = 
  Input with properties:

    p: [2x3 double]
>> myIn.p
ans =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```

Comment: U r very true, please tell me is there any other way like some Property Access Method to make this default, like I jist Enter `p` in my case and it shows value. ?

Comment: I need so because i'm also working with dynamic variables using `eval` and in your case, it couldn't access that. I need a method which is public and automatically stores in terminal variables.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully, but you can just set a default in `properties` (`p = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];`) and put logic in the constructor to reject the input if nothing (just Enter) is received (`xx = input('Enter array like [a b c; d e f;]'); if ~isempty(xx), obj.p = xx; end`)

Comment: @AhsanAli I'm not sure if you got what you needed out of my last comment, but I'm glad you accepted the answer. If it's helpful, upvotes are also appreciated.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah it is useful, and i'm totally satisfied with that. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `input`, you have to enter valid matlab code. Your command asks for a input like `[a b c; d e f;]`, but the variables a-f are unknown. If you are intending to create a char array, use `['abc';'def']`

Comment: No, I'm not intending to create char array, I want double data type values, What should I do in that case?